# Apache rewrite + Magento don't work as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

I need to implement the following rewrite rules for my Magento 1 store - to remove a query string if it contains either `param1` or `param2` and URI is not `/myfilter/`.

Here is an example:

```
www.mystore.com/myfilter/ --> www.mystore.com/myfilter/

www.mystore.com/myfilter/?param1=1 --> www.mystore.com/myfilter/param1=1

www.mystore.com/<something>/?param1=1 --> www.mystore.com/<something>/

www.mystore.com/<something>/?param2=2 --> www.mystore.com/<something>/
```

I added the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfilter/?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param2
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

before standard Magento redirects:

```
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But it works the wrong way.
These URLs work:

```
www.mystore.com/myfilter/ --> www.mystore.com/myfilter/

www.mystore.com/myfilter/?param3=1 --> www.mystore.com/myfilter/?param3=1

www.mystore.com/<something>/?param1=1 --> www.mystore.com/<something>/

www.mystore.com/<something>/?param2=2 --> www.mystore.com/<something>/
```

But when URI contains `/myfilter/` and either `param1` or `param2`, it is redirecting me to `/index.php`:

```
www.mystore.com/myfilter/?param1=1 --> www.mystore.com/index.php
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Try to post your question on Server's fault too.

Comment: @M.Gara This is **not** on topic for Server Fault. Look at Server Fault's [How to Ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's not a server fault, I can see the same behavior on different servers, including my local apache. It's something related to both Magento's rewrites and apache.

Comment: @theProgrammer101, I'm not completely sure what is incomplete / unverifiable you think?

Comment: Solved and question updated with a solution :)

Comment: Great that you found the solution, but please post it in an answer. Solutions do not belong in questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These rules made a trick I needed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php/)?myfilter/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param2
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myfilter/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/myfilter/ [L]
```